# Force Const Data Save In RAM not ROM

Tags: c++, c, arduino, arm, embedded

Can it be forced to save a const value in RAM instead of ROM on an embedded device instead of being a suggestion to the compiler. I want to keep the speed of reading from RAM but make sure the value is not changed some where in the code?

Comment: Why would you want a constant in RAM? RAM on the arduino is very tight and writing constants in there isn't the best idea?

Comment: Reading from flash takes more time than reading from RAM. But I dont want the value to change accidentally in the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can force a variable to be landed on data section (or wherever) and tell the compiler that it won't be modified:

`const int variable __attribute__((section(".data")));`

The way to indicate the section depends on the compiler, but normally `__attribute__` is the valid approach.

To know the section you want, check your start up code, there you will see their addresses and sizes (or check the linker).

Comment: Your code is invalid (will not compile) and even if you modify it  - on AVR will not do anything

Answer (score 1):

On Arduino they will be placed in the RAM. The problem is access to the FLASH which requires specific operations as AVR uC has separated address spaces.

Without special compiler extensions like gcc Named Address Spaces or PROGMEM you cant access the data in the FLASH.

So all `const` data will be placed in the RAM. You do not need to do anything.

---

You will need to do something if you decide to access them from the FLASH